# OpenId4Java not working for me

Tags: openid4java

Hi I am using openId4Java for my application but for any URL I got the following error. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks ...

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisException: 0x704: I/O transport error: Connection to "https://www.google.com" refused
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisException: 0x704: I/O transport error: Connection to "https://www.google.com" refused
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:214)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisException: 0x704: I/O transport error: Connection to "https://www.google.com" refused
    org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:478)
    org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:248)
    org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:232)
    org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:166)
    org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:147)
    org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:129)
    org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.discover(ConsumerManager.java:542)
    openIdTest.security.LoginManager.Login(LoginManager.java:51)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:154)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to "https://www.google.com" refused
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:127)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:147)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:101)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:381)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
    org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
    org.openid4java.util.HttpCache.head(HttpCache.java:335)
    org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:400)
    org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:248)
    org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:232)
    org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:166)
    org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:147)
    org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:129)
    org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.discover(ConsumerManager.java:542)
    openIdTest.security.LoginManager.Login(LoginManager.java:51)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:154)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you used google to be the OP, read [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID?hl=es-ES#endpoint).

In order to begin an OpenID authentication using a Google account you must perform the initial discovery to this URL: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id. instead of using the user identification URL.